# Rails fields_for in fields_for rows not associating with parent id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add some custom questions to the bottom of my form. However the id of the question isn't being associated with the answer field. How would I go about this?

input.html.erb

```
<% @event.event_questions.each do |question| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :event_question, question do |answer| %>
    <%= answer.simple_fields_for :event_answer do |e| %>
      <%= e.input :answer, label: question.question %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

output.html

```
<div class="form-group string required participant_event_question_event_answer_answer"><label class="string required control-label" for="participant_event_question_event_answer_answer"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Goals</label><input class="string required form-control" type="text" name="participant[event_question][event_answer][answer]" id="participant_event_question_event_answer_answer" /></div>
<div class="form-group string required participant_event_question_event_answer_answer"><label class="string required control-label" for="participant_event_question_event_answer_answer"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Action Plan</label><input class="string required form-control" type="text" name="participant[event_question][event_answer][answer]" id="participant_event_question_event_answer_answer" /></div>
<div class="form-group string required participant_event_question_event_answer_answer"><label class="string required control-label" for="participant_event_question_event_answer_answer"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Vision</label><input class="string required form-control" type="text" name="participant[event_question][event_answer][answer]" id="participant_event_question_event_answer_answer" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `question_id` in `answers` table, you can try the below code.

```
<% @event.event_questions.each do |question| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :event_question, question do |answer| %>
    <%= answer.simple_fields_for :event_answer do |e| %>
      <%= e.input :answer, label: question.question %>
      <%= e.input :question_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { :value => question.id }
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That was part of the answer.

Comment: Is it secure to have parent id as a form input? Sneaky user may change it thus editing answers to a different question.